# MySQL trigger end if syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

Unable to create trigger on update of specific field

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `add_event` AFTER  UPDATE ON `order_table` 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  IF NEW.status <=> OLD.status THEN
    INSERT INTO `events` SET 
      events.status = NEW.status, 
      events.order_id = NEW.order_id, 
      events.time_stamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  END IF;
delimiter ;
```

I am getting this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END IF;

Comment: You shouldn't have `, INSERT` after `UPDATE`

Comment: No such thing as and AFTER  UPDATE, INSERT  trigger - you need one of each.

Comment: Now I just think you need a `;` after `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to terminate your statement properly.

Comment: after `FOR EACH ROW ` you need a `begin` key word and after `end if;`you Need an `end;//`

Comment: SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger because the row change will have already occurred

Comment: @deadman Still getting same error  `CREATE TRIGGER `add_event` `BEFORE  UPDATE ON `order_table` `
  `FOR EACH ROW
  `BEGIN`
  `IF NEW.status <=> OLD.status THEN`
  `INSERT INTO `events` SET events.status = NEW.status, events.order_id =` `NEW.order_id, events.time_stamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
  `END IF;`
 ` END;`
`delimiter ;`

Comment: @AnanthSathvick there is no syntax error I have tested on online editor.

Comment: semicolon is missing after CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: You have a null safe equal test (<=>) in your code I suspect you are looking for a <> test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax error in below mysql trigger.

```
delimiter //
 CREATE TRIGGER add_event AFTER UPDATE ON order_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
         IF NEW.status <=> OLD.status THEN
            INSERT INTO `events` 
            SET events.status = NEW.status, 
            events.order_id = NEW.order_id, 
            events.time_stamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
         END IF;
     END;//
 delimiter ;
```

Comment: Works!! Thankyou :)

Comment: @deadman Ananth can't upvote, doesn't have enough rep points. I did though.

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table if exists t;
drop table if exists events;

create table t(order_id int, status varchar(1));
create table events(order_id int, time_stamp timestamp,status varchar(1));
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER t after update ON `t` 
 FOR EACH ROW 
 begin
 IF NEW.status <> OLD.status THEN
    INSERT INTO `events` 
        SET events.status = NEW.status, 
                events.order_id = NEW.order_id, 
                 events.time_stamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END IF ;
end //
 delimiter ;

 insert into t values(1,1);
 insert into events values(1,now(),1);
 update t set status = 2 where order_id = 1;
 select * from t;
 select * from events;

MariaDB [sandbox]>  select * from t;
+----------+--------+
| order_id | status |
+----------+--------+
|        1 | 2      |
+----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>  select * from events;
+----------+---------------------+--------+
| order_id | time_stamp          | status |
+----------+---------------------+--------+
|        1 | 2018-08-06 10:16:35 | 1      |
|        1 | 2018-08-06 10:16:35 | 2      |
+----------+---------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using if statement. You are checking everything <=>. Here is the solution :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `add_event` AFTER  UPDATE ON `order_table` 
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `events` SET events.status = NEW.status, events.order_id = NEW.order_id, events.time_stamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END;
 delimiter ;
```

Comment: Even I need to check if paricular field is updated, Insert if updated

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: You are checking everything. This IF statement always return true.